# Place node in center of nodes created by foreach angle loop

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've got this, which works fine:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tikz [>=Stealth]{
\foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}
  \node [circle, scale=.8] (\angle) at (\angle:.5) {0};
}

%\node at (0,0)   {0};
\end{document}
```

But I am trying to find the right way to uncomment the penultimate line so I can have a 0 (or any label) at the exact center.

Comment: `\tikz [>=Stealth]{
\foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}
  \node [circle, scale=.8] (\angle) at (\angle:.5) {0};
  \node at (0,0)   {O};
}`                                                                                                   doesn't work for you?

Comment: Yes, simple case of misplacing a bracket. Thanks to everyone for pointing this out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the following not do what you want?  I've explicitly placed the code to be looped over in braces and then place the `\node at (0,0)   {0};` within the argument of the `\tikz` macro.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tikz [>=Stealth]{
\foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}{
  \node [circle, scale=.8] (\angle) at (\angle:.5) {0};
}
\node at (0,0)   {0};
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is content of  *ferahfeza* comment ...

Comment: @Zarko It is also the OPs content.

Answer (score 2):

Better approach than `\tikz[...]{...}` is use `\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
c[>=Stealth] 
\foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}
  \node [circle, scale=.8] (\angle) at (\angle:.5) {0};
\node at (0,0)   {0};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: They are equivalent for this lenght of code.

Comment: Yes, it is, however, more clear is beginning and end of picture and less probability that you left part of image outside its environment as happens to OP. But it is true, that require more typing :)